# Copy and Paste issue in wysihtml editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i am using wysihtml editor if i paste "http://www.google.com" in wyshtml editor then pasted value comes in anchor tags as value instead of the value what i pasted . if i manually write "http://www.google.com" then anchor is dose not prefixed as a value.

so i want the value without anchor tag ,and i don't want to use any html code(like remove:{} ). please let me know the way to do this :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure the parser rule. Look at [this](https://github.com/Voog/wysihtml/blob/master/parser_rules/advanced.js) for a description.